# MySQL & PHP cross encryption / decryption algorithm?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, encryption

I'm looking for an encryption / decryption algorithm (method) that would work across MySQL (5.7.x) and PHP (5.6.x).

Problem: we have some processes via procs. and events within MySQL, one of them requires encrypting the user's id (send in email links). We then, in turn, need to grab that and decrypt within PHP for processing.

Is there a compatible algorithm that we can use that works cross platforms?

***Resolved**

I found my biggest problem was MySQL is actually limited to 16char / 128bit key. All my attempts with SHA256 failed because of that. In addition, I've discovered `openssl_encrypt()` is compatible out of the box (no needing to pad):

```php
$salt = substr(hash('sha256', 'My secret passphrase'), 0, 16);
$text = 12345;

print_r(array(
    'salt' => $salt,
    'aes-128-ecb' => openssl_encrypt($text, 'aes-128-ecb', $salt),
));
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [salt] => 760624f7a7f6e8e4
    [aes-128-ecb] => blXklI80Q+KmPH909qUyWw==
)
```

MySQL Response:

```
set @salt = SUBSTRING(SHA2('My secret passphrase',256), 1, 16);
select @salt as salt
    , TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(12345, @salt));
```

Results in:

```
salt                TO_BASE64(AES_ENCRYPT(12345, @salt))
760624f7a7f6e8e4    blXklI80Q+KmPH909qUyWw==
```

Comment: You can probably use `mcrypt` in php to encrypt the data, and use `AES_DECRYPT` to decrypt the data in mysql.

Comment: I've been trying that. I'm having trouble finding an mcrypt algorithm that matches. Have a command off hand that works? (edit: fixed typo)

Comment: If both PHP and MySQL have access to the decryption key I have doubts that this is secure in any meaningful way. Have you had your code audited by a security professional who can confirm that you're doing it correctly?

Comment: You're right and it's something we do plan to look into. Right now, we're just needing a simple method to encrypt via MySQL and decrypt via PHP. We're encrypting non-sensitive information only; this is more for obscurity than secure credit card storage. We just need a simple way to make things just a bit protected in links sent to our users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that I found doing some research :-

PHP code to encrypt:

```
// MySQL uses 16 bytes key for 128 encryption/decryption
$key = "ABCDEF0123456789";

$plaintext = "This string was AES-128 / EBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted.";
// Optionally UTF-8 encode
$plaintext_utf8 = utf8_encode($plaintext);
// Find out what's your padding
$pad_len = 16 - (strlen($plaintext_utf8) % 16);
// Padd your text
$plaintext_utf8 = str_pad($plaintext_utf8, (16 * (floor(strlen($plaintext_utf8) / 16) + 1)), chr($pad_len));

// Encryption
mt_srand();
$td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, false);
// Generates a warning about empty IV but it's Ok
$ciphertext = mcrypt_generic($td, $plaintext_utf8);
mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
$ciphertext = mysql_real_escape_string($ciphertext);

// Store in MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "test", "test", "test");
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
$mysqli->query("insert into test(content) value ('$ciphertext')");
$mysqli->close();
```

SQL query to search for `string was:`

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(content,'ABCDEF0123456789') AS CHAR) AS content
FROM test
WHERE CAST(AES_DECRYPT(content,'ABCDEF0123456789') AS CHAR) like '%string was%';
```

Output :-

```
This string was AES-128 / EBC / ZeroBytePadding encrypted.
```

Comment: Have any idea why keys greater than 16 don't match? I got this, with a 16 char key. But if I use something larger, bin, hex, things no longer work. Such as: hex2bin(hash('sha256', 'My secret passphrase'));

Comment: Okay, answered this question of mine. From the docs, it says "but you can extend them to 256 bits by modifying the source" and I didn't realize they mean the MySQL Source Code. Without doing that, MySQL is limited to a 16char (128bit) key. We'll continue with that limitation in mind. Thanks!

Comment: Do not use `mysql_real_escape_string` when using `mysqli`. These are incompatible. Use [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @RyanVincent We're not encrypting passwords. We never encrypt those: those are hashed only. Note: We need decryption in my use-case. Never use a decryptable method for storing passwords!

Answer (score 0):

You can do with PHP [mcrypt_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [mcrypr_decrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) using a simple VARCHAR column in your database.
From the docs:

```
$key = pack('H*', "bcb04b7e103a0cd8b54763051cef08bc55abe029fdebae5e1d417e2ffb2a00a3");

$iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

$plain_text = 'some text blabla';

$encrypt_text = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plain_text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

echo $encrypt_text;
//should output some hash

$decrypt_text = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key,
                                $encrypt_text, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv_dec);

echo $decryp_text;
//should output 'some text blabla'
```

Comment: You're suggesting encrypt the user's id before hand, using PHP, and store that? It's a way. I was thinking more dynamically encrypting: MySQL encrypts and sends; PHP receives and decrypts. No storing of the encrypted data.

Comment: My guess is if you need to manipulate encrypted data, is because you have a need for security and privacy here. If you store plain text data, there is a flaw in your security, which may be exploited. Also, doing the way you want, you'll have two points with possible failure, two points to debug, ... More complexity, more work, more chance to fail, ...